# Mapbox, Angular, jest unit test fails

Tags: angular, mapbox, ts-jest, mapbox-gl

I have a mapbox.service.ts
`import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';`
In this service I just create this mapbox map

```
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  accessToken: this.accessToken,
  container: 'mapbox-container',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
  center: { lat: 43.238949, lng: 76.889709 },
  zoom: this.currentZoom,
});
```

Application works fine.
However, when I run jest unit tests, this mapbox.service.spec.ts fails.

```
ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined

      1 | import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    > 2 | import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
```

Inside mapbox.service.spec.ts I did not add any test cases.

```
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MapboxService } from './mapbox.service';

describe('Service: Mapbox', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [MapboxService],
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([MapboxService], (service: MapboxService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Why TextDecoder is not defined?

I changed my setup.jest.ts file to

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import { TextEncoder } from 'node:util';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
```

On the Internet I found this solution, then I tried it, but it shows other errors:

```
Test suite failed to run

    src/setup.jest.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'node:util' or its corresponding type declarations.

    2 import { TextEncoder } from 'node:util';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/setup.jest.ts:4:1 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'global'.

    4 global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
```

I'm just using a regular MapBox map, nothing special.
Anyone using Mapbox in their application, how to fix this unit test failure?

Comment: Fixed that. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood why the error occurs. This is because the Node version and the mapbox-gl versions are not compatible with each other.

1. I downgraded my Node version, but the error still persists.
   My node version is v20 downgraded to (v18, v16, v14).
2. I did not touch Node version and then started downgrading mapbox-gl version.
   My current version of mapbox-gl is v3.1.2., then I downgraded it until the error message disappeared. So, when mapbox-gl version became v2.15.0, then the error went away.

Now, everything works fine, it may be helpful for those who may face the same problem in the future :)